# Database lookup : How to use CachedMap in Trident

Tags: bigdata, apache-storm, trident

How do we use `CachedMap` in Trident. 
My use case is such that, I will be doing some database and want to store that information in cache or trident state. 
Next time when I get any tuple, I want to query the trident state or cache before querying database. 
I don't get required data in trident state/cache, I will be querying the database and updating the trident state/cache.
Please let me know how do we achieve this or if there any link to help me out with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

CachedMap wraps your IBackingMap and also implements IBackingMap.  It calls your store when it doesn't have a cached value.

`new CachedMap(myIBackingMap, cacheSize)`

See example usage in [trident-memcached](https://github.com/nathanmarz/trident-memcached/blob/master/src/jvm/trident/memcached/MemcachedState.java#L128)